TS target config does not support browserlist
It seems TS target config does not support browserlist's browsers versions like "Chrome >= 48", found related issue#19183 and issue#53373.
I created a utils package, currently, I set the compilerOptions.target to "es5" and build the package by tsc command. And the project which use this utils package must be transpile the code to chrome: 49, see below webpack config module rules:
{
  test: /\.m?js/,
  use: {
    loader: "babel-loader",
    options: {
      presets: [["@babel/env", { targets: { chrome: 49 } }]],
    },
  },
},

The question is:
I don't think "es5" is equivalent to "chrome: 49". So, build this utils package with target "es5" will not be safe.
And, I need to skip transpile the files of this utils package in a project by webpack + babel-loader. Which means I want to use the pre-transpiled files directly in the project. Do I have to switch to webpack or some other bundler that supports browserlist to build this utils package with "chrome: 49" target?
